# python - timedelta and two time ranges

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I would like to find how many hours from timedelta are inside Day and Night range.

#### Time-Start:

```
>>> dt_start = datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 19, 16, 0)
```

#### Time-Stop:

```
>>> dt_stop = datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 20, 3, 0)
```

#### Timedelta:

```
>>> dtd = dt_stop - dt_start
>>> print(dtd.seconds//3600)
>>> 11
```

#### Time ranges:

```
Day = 7am-22pm
Night = 22pm-7am
```

For this example the right output will be:

```
Day hours: 6:00
Night hours: 5:00
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Will both dates always be in the same day or can they span days?

Comment: Shouldn't `print(dtd.seconds//360)` return 110, not 11 (there are 3600 seconds in an hour)? Also- is it possible that the timedelta will cover multiple days and nights?

Comment: @MichałGórny dates span max into next day

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thx for typo. The timedelta will cover max two days (when time_stop is inside next day).

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to specify the transition point for day and night, and calculate the delta to that and then the delta to the end-point:

```
day_start = 7
night_start = 22

day_hours = 0
night_hours = 0
if dt_start.hour < night_start:
    dt_night = dt_start.replace(hour=night_start)
    day_hours = (dt_night - dt_start).seconds // 3600
    night_hours = (dt_end - dt_night).seconds // 3600
```

This is a rather naive setup, as it won't support multiple-day spans and such. Consider it a starting point.